# I want to convert a non functioning gas post light mantel to a 12 volt lamp fixture

Tags: landscaping

I am installing 12v landscape lights for a walkway and would like to add a non working gas lamp to the system.
Has anyone ever retrofitted a post lamp to a 12 volt light?

Are there any 12v led lights on the market?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of physical distance are we talking about?  Will your landscape lights work on 24V?

Comment: In my area there are many gas post lights that have been converted to electric.  Most use a 24 volt transformer with two 12volt 1156 bayonet base auto bulbs wired in series and a 24 volt photocell.(the existing gas pipe is used disconnected as conduit for the wire).  Google "gas light conversion" there are many products on the market to help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The lamp post is about 15' from an electrical source. I was planning to install a 12v transformer and add 6 12v walkway lights to the conversion project.